# Obtaining ghost entities with difference tool?

Tags: qgis

I have a vector map of land use for Europe. It contains square polygons which are each one from a type of land use.
As there are 19 million of entities, I would like to delete the entities that correspond to the sea as I don't need them.

So I selected all the entities that are sea.
I saved the selected features to a new layer.

Finally, I used the tool Difference (geoprocessing Tool -> difference) to do :
all my entities - sea = the entities I need.

I obtained a map that looks perfect, but the table of attributes is exactly the same that the original one : it contains the sea, so still 19 millions entities.
So what is really strange is that if I try to select sea, there is no entity, but in the table there are. I selected all the sea entities in my table and on the map nothing is in "yellow".
It's like ghost entities.

Then I really don't understand.

My QGIS version is 2.18.9

Comment: Are you sure you are not opening the attribute table of original land use map before using difference tool?

Comment: Yes, I checked several times

Comment: Have you closed QGIS and re-opened the new file?
I would suggest NOT using the difference tool as that involves geometry while your selection is purely on attributes. Simply select the sea entities, then invert the selection, then save those.

Comment: Yes I tried this too, I even re started my computer. Ok, thank you I will know it now. I will do this way thank you.

Comment: How can I simply reverse the selection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have selected the sea-entities, open the attribute table and press this button:

[image]

After this you can right click the layer --> Save As and check "Save only selected features" to export the data without sea-polygons.

Comment: Thank you for your help, didn't know this tip. So now I will do that instead of difference tool when there is no geometry involved :)